# crawler get external website search result

Tags: java, selenium, web-crawler, nutch

1. What is the best practice and library I can use to key in search textbox on external website and collect the search result?
2. How do tackle website with different search box and checkbox and collect the result?
3. Can Selenium be used to automate this?
4. Should I use Heritrix or nutch? Which one is better? I heard nutch comes with plugins. Which one has a bigger community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

- The Selenium API
- HtmlUnit
- Htmlparser

etc.

Comment: any reference articles...  how to get the result from selenium and pass to htmlparser. i though selenium can automate testing and cant get result...

Comment: it's API can. You can open the pages for those three technologies and see the 'Getting started' or the user manual - it is a good reference